# Changing colour in a complex logo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, logo

I have a complex logo that needs color change in photoshop. It's not my original design, so the orange logo you see is my original reference in good quality.

How do I change this to the green tones, attached, but of low quality?

Have tried hue/saturation and color balance and filters but nothing comes even close. Its a logo I will need to change in the future to copy pink, brown, and blue tones the client has used on other labels. Thanks for any ideas.

[image]

---

The green version has been made and used but now the client wants to increase the size of the label. The version I have is too small and came to me in low quality. So, basically I have the orange logo that needs to be adapted with all other colors.

Comment: HI Beli, welcome to GD.SE! Can you describe what "nothing comes even close" when using a hue/saturation adjustment layer? What about changing the color with an adjustment layer doesn't work for you, are you not getting the right green tones? Is the green version what you have made or what you're trying to get to?

Comment: Before starting to generate unexpected costs check your legal status. You wrote "It's not my design". So, do you have a right to generate own versions? That depends on what is the contract and what your local law says. Get a lawyer if you do not know. In an unlucky case the copyright owner can pull a substantial amount of money from your pocket in a court of law.

Answer (score 6):

The real answer is

Re-draw-it the proper way... And charge for it. Shapes made in vectors, elements in groups or layers so they are easily selected.

If you keep perpetuating the bad habits of non-professional designers (taking bad quality assets from clients and work on them without correcting them), you will be stuck on this kind of bad results and projects.